# Is there any way to avoid committing debugger in git?

Tags: git, debugging, github, push, git-push

I have come across a situation in which I have commited debugger in git and then pushed it on GitHub.

Is there any way to avoid this?

For example, whenever I commit some code which contains `debugger` then `git` should give me some sort of warning that your commit contains debugger

I visited a few websites and gists related to this which tells us to add git hooks [here](https://gist.github.com/wacko/62560b45c1d191859d6b) to avoid committing `debugger`

Is this the only way to avoid this?

Comment: generally speaking, yes, git hooks are the way to go -- you could also accomplish it with a smudge filter though that's not exactly what smudge filters are designed for.  (disclaimer: I wrote this framework) if you're looking for a git hooks framework, it's pretty easy to get started with https://pre-commit.com -- your specific hook (depending on language) is probably already implemented (and if it isn't, a `pygrep` (regex) based hook is a quick-and-dirty alternative)

Comment: Thanks pre-commit.com is pretty helpful

Comment: there's also https://githooks.com/ if you're looking for other choices